# Azure DevOps Service Connection does not work with custom job

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure Devops I am able to create an ACR Service Connection and use the `Docker@2` task to login, build and push an image - as part of the first job of my pipeline.

In the second job of my pipeline I want to use the image I built in the first job and run some stuff inside it. However even though I supply the service connection name(the same as first job) my pipeline keeps failing with `'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`.

How can I make this work with using the `Service Connection` that works just fine for the 1st job?

```
- job: BuildDockerImage
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build /push image
    inputs:
      command: buildAndPush
      repository: XYZ
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      containerRegistry: ABC
      tags: |
        $(Build.SourceVersion)

- job: TestCode
  dependsOn: BuildDockerImage
  condition: succeeded()
  timeoutInMinutes: 200
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  container:
    image: ABC/XYZ:$(Build.SourceVersion)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue , it could be the lack of `endpoint` parameter.

Containers can be hosted on registries other than Docker Hub. To host an image on Azure Container Registry or another private container registry, add a service connection to the private registry. Then you can reference it in a container spec:

```
container:
  image: myprivate/registry:xxx
  endpoint: private_dockerhub_connection
```

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints) you can refer to .